# React: Passing an object to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I'm trying to make a replica of the Spotify Web Player by using the Spotify Web API. Right now, I'm trying to set the activePlaylist with an onClick event handler. However, when I pass my playlist object to the event handler method, the object is undefined. I've tried to fix this for a long time. Do you have any tips?

NOTE: It'll map the names to the page just fine, but the object becomes undefined when I pass it to the event handler method.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/playlists.css';

class Playlists extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activePlaylist: null
    };
  }

  setActivePlaylist(playlist) {
    console.log('From setActivePlaylist');
    console.log(playlist.name); //this logs as undefined
  }

  render() {
    const {playlists} = this.props;

    return(
      <div className='playlists'>
        <h4 id='playlist-label'>Playlists</h4>
        {this.props.playlists
          ?
          (this.props.playlists.items.map((playlist, index)=>
            <a href="#" onClick={(playlist) => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)}>
              <h4
              key={index}
              >
                {playlist.name}
              </h4>
            </a>
          ))
          :
          (<h4>Loading playlists...</h4>)
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlists;
```

Comment: Can you try wrapping the <a> tag in a <div> then give the div the same onClick handler?

Comment: Probably not the cause but should you be binding the method in your constructor - this.setActivePlaylist = this.setActivePlaylist.bind(this);

Comment: @yourfavoritedev Just did it! The result is the same.

Comment: can you show us the shape of playlists prop

Comment: Try it this way  `onClick={() => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)}` to access the playlist parameter via closure

Comment: @ScottMcCulloch I've read that's one way to do it. What's the advantage of binding it in the constructor over how I've implemented the method? Thanks for the feedback, by the way!

Comment: @GabrielLopez This did it!!! Can you explain to me why this worked?

Comment: @JaredMoats   Because of function scopes and parameters, when you click on something, a callback function gets called, in this case `(playlist) => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)` but "playlist" parameter does not exists on the button context, so an "undefined" value goes into the "setActivePlaylist" function, `onClick={() => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)}` when using this code, javascript uses the closure created to access the playlist parameter, the one passed into the .map callback

Comment: Here, take a look at this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 1):

You will want to bind the context so you have access to the the class. Here's what it could look like the following snipped. I broke apart the logic simply for readability.

Also, you were trying to override the parameter of the event with the same name as the passed in variable - thus "playlist" was the event object, not the object you were expecting"

```
onClick={/* this be no good-->*/ (**playlist**) => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)}
```

You can see a demo here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-passing-an-object-to-state?file=Playlists.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Playlists extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activePlaylist: null
    };

    // Need to bind the scoped context so we have access to "Playlists" component.
    this.renderLink = this.renderLink.bind(this);
  }

  setActivePlaylist(playlist) {
    console.log('From setActivePlaylist');
    console.log(playlist.name);
  }

  render() {
    const {items} = this.props.playlists

    return(
      <div className='playlists'>
        <h4 id='playlist-label'>Playlists</h4>
        {items
          ? items.map(this.renderLink)
          : <h4>Loading playlists...</h4>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderLink(playlist, index) {
    return (
      <a onClick={() => this.setActivePlaylist(playlist)}>
        <h4 key={index}>
            {playlist.name}
          </h4>
        </a>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlists;
```

Also make sure you bind setActivePlaylist in constructor or make it arrow function